# How to split ArrayList into another List

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to split an ArrayList into separate blocks. I have a function that returns table data collected in jsoupie, just as individual elements.
I wonder how to make a second list, so that it consisted of every 5 subsequent elements of the first list.

```
   example:
    1 list:
    lista1.get (0) = Monday;
    lista1.get (1) = Tuesday;
    ...
    lista1.get (6) = Sunday;

    and here I would like to make it

                     //lista1.get(1) .. lista1.get(6)
    lista2.get (0) = Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday;
    lista2.get (1) = any, other data contained in, this, leaves, stated below;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to create a list of list? use subList on the first list and add to a new list

Comment: From you Question it's look like you should try list of list.

Comment: Yes, I would like to create list of every 5 elements head lists, but I get data from JSOUP table (website) , and I don't know how many datas is there, so I want to split this array by every 5 subsequent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written two methods for you. One splits your list into list of lists, another one groups nested lists into single string.

```
    public class LinkedListSplitByFive {

        private static List<List<String>> splitByGroupAsList(List<String> list, int elementsInGroup) {
            List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            List<String> group = new ArrayList<String>(elementsInGroup);
            for (String s : list) {
                group.add(s);
                if (group.size() == elementsInGroup) {
                    result.add(group);
                    group = new ArrayList<String>(elementsInGroup);
                }
            }
            if (!group.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(group);
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static List<String> splitByGroupAsString(List<String> list, int elementsInGroup) {
            List<List<String>> lists = splitByGroupAsList(list, elementsInGroup);
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(lists.size());

            for (List<String> group : lists) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < group.size(); i++) {
                    sb.append(group.get(i));
                    if (i == group.size() - 1) {
                        sb.append(";");
                    } else {
                        sb.append(", ");
                    }
                }
                result.add(sb.toString());
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11");

            System.out.println(splitByGroupAsList(list, 5));
            // [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11]]

            System.out.println(splitByGroupAsString(list, 5));
            // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5;, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;, 11;]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was so helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> flatList = Arrays.asList(
          "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11");

    List<List<String>> outer = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    int cnt = 0;
    List<String> inner = new ArrayList<String>(5);

    for (String str : flatList) {
        inner.add(str);    // fill inner list

        if (++cnt == 5) {
            outer.add(inner);
            inner = new ArrayList<String>(5);
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }

    if (!inner.isEmpty()) {
        outer.add(inner);
    }

    System.out.println(outer);
}
```

Result of this code is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11]]
```

Comment: But, can you explain me, what should I do when I want to return List<String>? Because now, I'm getting a List<List<String>

Comment: @Algeroth check my answer below. It answers this question too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a map of Object* with List. 
* Change Object for whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you need a list of lists as output, you can try this. I haven't tried compiling it, so there might be some syntax errors and typos. But the main idea is to keep picking 5 elements each time from the original list and adding those into new list. And keeping a `listOfLists`, which eventually contains all such new lists.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    int size=list.length %5=0?i/5:i/5+1;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        listOfLists.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(list, i*5, i*5+5));
    }
# return listOfLists;
```

Comment: Considering you are using `list.size()`, list is the subclass of Collection. Then how can you pass it as argument to `Arrays.copyOfRange` which accepts only plain arrays?

Comment: I considered input `list` as an `array`. I should have used `length` attribute instead of `size()`, thanks for pointing it out. Even if the input is `ArrayList`, one can convert it into an array before passing it to `Arrays.copyOfRange()` method. Of corse, it might not be the most efficient way.